# SObjectType for RecordType?

Tags: record-type, static

Is there a statically accessible SObjectType for RecordType?

```
System.debug(Account.SObjectType); // Result: Account
System.debug(RecordType.SObjectType); // Result: SObjectType
```

[RecordType class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm) explains why `RecordType.SObjectType` is different.

I know I can get the Type from an Id:

```
Id rtId = '012C0000000UrhQ';
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, rtId.getSObjectType()); // RecordType
```

But is there also a static accessor, like for all other types?

Comment: Everything works as expected. It looks strange but you have two different expressions.

 1. `RecordType.SObjectType` indeed evaluates to a `Schema.SObjectField` because there is a Field `SObjectType` on `RecordType`.
 2. `Account.SObjectType` indeed evaluates the specific SObjectType `Account`

Comment: I rewrote the question, thanks for your help @RobertSösemann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the describe:

```
DescribeSObjectResult describe = SObjectType.RecordType;
```

From the describe, you can then use the `getSObjectType()` method:

```
SObjectType schemaType = SObjectType.RecordType.getSObjectType();
```

---

As noted in the comments, in this case you retrieve the `SObjectField` with this name where you would normally return the `SObjectType`:

```
SObjectField someField = RecordType.DeveloperName;
SObjectField typeField = RecordType.SObjectType;
```

---

You might run into the same issue on other objects with a field so named, such as:

- `FieldPermissions`
- `ObjectPermissions`
- `QueueSobject`
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `getSObjectType()` as a static method on any concrete `sObject` types. It's resolved at run time rather than compile time (which is what I'm assuming you actually mean by static), but probably fits your purpose:

```
System.debug(RecordType.getSObjectType());//Result: RecordType
```

Comment: I can't wrap my head around why this version doesn't throw a compile error. It should say `Variable does not exist: RecordType`, but when I run it through Execute Anonymous, I get no error. Weird...

Comment: @AdrianLarson Best I can tell, using the "RecordType" identifier puts the compiler in "sObject Land", where the rules are different.  Similarly, `RecordType.class.sObjectType` is the same as `RecordType.sObjectType`, but `Type.ForName('RecordType').sObjectType` is invalid, even though `RecordType.class.equals(Type.ForName('RecordType'))` is true.